# Install JDK 1.5 in OSX 10.10

Tags: java, osx-yosemite, java-5

I'm using Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite), i have to use JDK 1.5 for legacy application development. I'm having troubles when installing JDK 1.5.

I'm able to find the 1.5.dmg (http://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1359/en_US/JavaForMacOSX10.5Update10.dmg), unfortunately this can't be installed in Yosemite.

Does anyone know how should i install JDK 1.5 in OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://gist.github.com/bric3/1163008 and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7856472/will-compiling-for-java-1-5-on-java-1-7-still-work

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh). After installing it do the following:

```
brew tap caskroom/versions
```

See which versions of Java is available:

```
brew cask search java
```

Install the relevant version:

```
brew install java6
```

To manage the versions you could use something like `jenv`. Install:

```
brew install jenv
```

Change version:

```
jenv add <javaPath>
```

Comment: as of 2021 it's `brew tap homebrew/cask-versions`