# Install JDK 1.5 in OSX 10.10 Yosemite

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, osx-yosemite, java-5

I use OS X Yosemite (10.10.2) and I have to use JDK 1.5 for legacy application development. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28182787/install-jdk-1-5-in-osx-10-10) post which refers to [this](https://gist.github.com/bric3/1163008) script to install JDK 4,5,6 in Lion and Mavericks. In comments I found this two lines

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :JavaVM:JVMMaximumFrameworkVersion 14.*.*" ./Resources/Info.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :JavaVM:JVMMaximumSystemVersion "$osx_version".*" ./Resources/Info.plist
```

have to be changed by

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete :JavaVM:JVMMaximumFrameworkVersion" ./Resources/Info.plist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Delete :JavaVM:JVMMaximumSystemVersion" ./Resources/Info.plist
```

to achieve compatibility with Yosemite. I ran this script and this is content of my `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions` directory

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10  8 apr 14:36 1.4 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10  8 apr 14:36 1.4.2 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10  9 apr 11:01 1.5 -> ./1.5.0_30
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10  9 apr 11:01 1.5.0 -> ./1.5.0_30
drwxr-xr-x  9 root  wheel  306  9 apr 11:01 1.5.0_30
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10  8 apr 14:36 1.6 -> CurrentJDK
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   10  8 apr 14:36 1.6.0 -> CurrentJDK
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel  238  8 apr 14:36 A
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    1  8 apr 14:36 Current -> A
```

In Eclipse preferences **Java->Installed JREs->Execution Environments**, there is not any JRE 1.5

[image]

and probably this is the reason why I cannot build projects in Java 5, because I get errors:

```
Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.5. There are no JREs installed in the workspace that are strictly compatible with this environment.
```

In Eclipse preferences **Installed JREs** - JSE-1.5 refers to correct path

[image]

In project preferences **Java Build Path** contains **J2SE-1.5**

[image]

and **Java Compiler** in project preferences is set correctly as well.

[image]

This is content of `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.5.0_30` directory

[image]

This thread refers to my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523955/build-path-specifies-execution-environment-j2se-1-5-there-are-no-jres-installed) post.

Comment: Why would you want to install Java 1.5? PS: not my downvote.

Comment: In this thread you can see why in some answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846573/how-to-get-jdk-1-5-on-mac-osx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution to your problem might be [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22584427/what-is-compiler-compliance-level-in-eclipse).

Eclipse is a powerful IDE, and as such can tell a 1.6/1.7/1.8 JRE to run as if it was a 1.5 JRE. I am not familiar with using this, but it looks a lot easier than downloading an entirely different JDK.

To change the compiler compliance level, go to your `Project Settings -> Java Compiler`

[image: Java Compiler Settings]

Untick `Use compliance from execution environment` and ensure that `Use default compliance settings` is ticked, and that the box alongside that is set to `1.5`.

Then you can change back to using your JDK 1.7.

Please let me know if this worked, as I can post an answer that walks through installing a new JRE for you, if this hasn't helped.